I've using upi_pay & flutter_upi packages, I'm getting an error "upi_pay/flutter_upi -> ext.kotlin_version should be above 1.5.40 or more
I've tried the below to resolve it

updating the version in the package (upi_pay.dart & flutter_upi.dart) to 2.0.10

updating the ext.kotlin_version of my project/gradle to 2.0.10

forked those packages and created my own with updated kotlin version, and used it in  pubsec.yaml


Still I can't resolve it.  What should I do??
I'm want to integrate UPI gateways in my flutter app to enable P2P transactions between users,

Please share your build.gradle files and your pubspec.yaml.

Update your kotlin version in settings.gradle file as below
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.25" apply false

or if you using older version
update kotlin version in android/app/build.grade file
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.25'  ///update kotlin version
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
}


I already tried it, still does'nt work
